# How to convert between columns and rows in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

scenario 1

original dataframe:

a b c d e f g

new dataframe:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

scenario 2

original dataframe:

g f e d c b a

new dataframe:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

My question is how to perform the above transformations?

Comment: Use the transpose method `df.T`, where `df` is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcdefg'))
df_new = pd.DataFrame([col for col in df.columns], columns=['column_to_rows'])

print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add ".T" to your dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
Out[99]: 
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
5  f
6  g

pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']).T

Out[100]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
```